# Using dynamic memory in C++

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, new-operator

Is this code correct?

```cpp
int *set_new (int choice) {
   int *new_choice {new int};
   *new_choice = choice;
   return new_choice;
}
```

Should I delete `*new_choice` after the value is returned, because `*new_choice` is on the memory heap?

```cpp
int *set_new (int choice) {
   int *new_choice {new int};
   *new_choice = choice;
   return new_choice;
   delete new_choice;
}
```

Or, do I need to delete it where the function is finished calling? if not deleted, will it cause a memory leak?

I learned on a website if you use dynamic memory (new) immediately after that delete (delete) so there is no memory leak.

The function is called in `main`:

```cpp
int main () {
 int *b {new_choice (23)};
 printf ("% d", *b);
 delete b;
}
```

Comment: The `delete` statement in your 2nd `set_new()` example won't ever be executed anyways. Your compiler should have told you that.

Answer (score 0):

You must not delete what will be used. The pointer assigned to `new_choice` will be used by the caller of `set_new`, so you must not free that.

Also you cannot delete things after returning in the function to return because `return` means the execution of the function ends at that point and the execution returns to the caller.

```
int *set_new (int choice) {
   int *new_choice {new int};
   *new_choice = choice;
   return new_choice;
   delete new_choice; // this statement won't be reached
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int *set_new (int choice) {
   int *new_choice {new int};
   *new_choice = choice;
   return new_choice;
   delete new_choice;
}
```

The `delete` line will never be executed. Function ends with a `return` statement (among others). If you try to remove `delete` before `return`, it will be executed, but the pointer returned will be invalid, so it's pointless.

Your final example is correct, you should `delete` after you are done using the pointed-to object.